# Android Sqlite database locked while performing bulk insertion

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Am creating medical dictionary with more than 20k entries. When am saving this data for offline usage, app crashes due to database locked. How do I solve this issue?

my insertion function

```
public static void saveWords(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, Context context, JSONArray response) {
        DbHelper helper = new DbHelper(context);


        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Finalising...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String wordId = object.getString("wordid");
                String category = object.getString("category");
                String word = object.getString("word");
                String meaning = object.getString("meaning");
                String letter = object.getString("letter");

                if (!wordExists(context, wordId)) {
                    contentValues.put(DbConstants.WORD_ID, wordId);
                    contentValues.put(DbConstants.CATEGORY, category);
                    contentValues.put(DbConstants.WORD, word);
                    contentValues.put(DbConstants.MEANING, meaning);
                    contentValues.put(DbConstants.LETTER, letter);
                    contentValues.put(DbConstants.STATUS, "0");

                    db.insert(DbConstants.TABLE_WORDS, null, contentValues);
                }
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            appCompatActivity.recreate();
        }

    }
```

wordExists method:

```
private static boolean wordExists(Context context, String wordId) {
       DbHelper helper = new DbHelper(context);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {DbConstants.WORD_ID};
        String whereClause = DbConstants.WORD_ID + " = ? ";
        String whereArgs[] = {wordId};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DbConstants.TABLE_WORDS, columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return true;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return false;

    }
```

I can't seem to understand where problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sometime I have gotten solution. My problem was, I was trying to reopen the database when it's already busy. Actually what messed my work is `wordExists` method. This is my new code:

```
 public static void saveWords(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, Context context, JSONArray response) {
        DbHelper helper = new DbHelper(context);


        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Finalising...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String wordId = object.getString("wordid");
                String category = object.getString("category");
                String word = object.getString("word");
                String meaning = object.getString("meaning");
                String letter = object.getString("letter");

                String[] columns = {DbConstants.WORD_ID};
                String whereClause = DbConstants.WORD_ID + " = ? ";
                String whereArgs[] = {wordId};

                Cursor cursor = db.query(DbConstants.TABLE_WORDS, columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
                    contentValues.put(DbConstants.WORD_ID, wordId);
                    contentValues.put(DbConstants.CATEGORY, category);
                    contentValues.put(DbConstants.WORD, word);
                    contentValues.put(DbConstants.MEANING, meaning);
                    contentValues.put(DbConstants.LETTER, letter);
                    contentValues.put(DbConstants.STATUS, "0");

                    db.insert(DbConstants.TABLE_WORDS, null, contentValues);

                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            appCompatActivity.recreate();
        }


        }
    }
```

I was trying to establish new connections when previous connection is still on process. Within the same transaction, database connection should be established once.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure the following things to store data offline:

- Saving cache files
- Pass a timeout values as an option
- Enabling Offline Capabilities

Comment: Completely out of topic

Answer (score 0):

First, `DbHelper helper = new DbHelper(context)` is expensive class. Is there any use-case that you have to recreate an instance for every call of `wordExists`. As you said, there is more than 20k entries, so there is more than 20k instances create again and again...

Second, If I am not wrong, this function `db.setTransactionSuccessful();` will close the db. And you know, when db is close before ending transaction, it will cause the error.

It should be like this

```
finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        appCompatActivity.recreate();
    }
```